# Using I2C dev driver

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, i2c

I want to configure a sensor over the I2C bus using the I2C-dev module. 
The required I2C bus is up and running, however, I cannot seem to receive any data from the sensor. Could anyone please help me debug the below code. All the sensor registers are 8 bit.

```
  int main()
{
    int devFile=0;
    const char *devFileName="/dev/i2c-1";
    char writeBuf[2];
    uint16_t readBuf[2];
    uint16_t tempReading = 0;

    /* Initialize I2C interface */  
    devFile = hdc2010_i2c_init(devFileName, HDC2010_ADDR);

    /* Configuring the sensor and trigerring measurement */
    writeBuf[0] = HDC2010_CONFIG; 
    writeBuf[1] = 0x57;
    hdc2010_i2c_write(devFile, writeBuf, 2);

    writeBuf[0] = HDC2010_INTERRUPT_CONFIG; 
    writeBuf[1] = 0x78;
    hdc2010_i2c_write(devFile, writeBuf, 2);

    writeBuf[0] = HDC2010_MEASUREMENT_CONFIG; 
    writeBuf[1] = 0x03;
    hdc2010_i2c_write(devFile, writeBuf, 2);

    /* Reading temperature data from the registers */
    writeBuf[0] = HDC2010_TEMP_LOW; 
    hdc2010_i2c_write(devFile, writeBuf, 1);
    readBuf[0] = hdc2010_i2c_read(devFile, 1);

    writeBuf[0] = HDC2010_TEMP_HIGH; 
    hdc2010_i2c_write(devFile, writeBuf, 1);
    readBuf[1] = hdc2010_i2c_read(devFile, 1);

    /* 
     * Converting the temperature to readable format 
     * Formula Source : HDC2010 Datasheet
     */
    tempReading = ((readBuf[1] << 8) | (readBuf[0]));
    tempReading = ((tempReading/65536)*165)-40;

    printf("\nTemp: %d\n",tempReading);
}

    int hdc2010_i2c_init(const char *devFileName, int slaveAddr)
{
    int devFile;

    /* Opening I2C device file */
    devFile=open(devFileName,O_RDWR);

    if (devFile < 0)
    {
        printf("\nError opening the %s device file.\n",devFileName);
        exit (1);
    }

    /* Selecting HDC2010 by its slave address */
    if (ioctl(devFile,I2C_SLAVE,slaveAddr) < 0)
    {
        printf("\nFailed to select HDC2010(addr=%u)\n",HDC2010_ADDR);
        exit (1);
    }

    return devFile;
}

    void hdc2010_i2c_write(int devFile, char *buf, int numBytes)
{
    write(devFile, buf, numBytes);
}

    uint16_t hdc2010_i2c_read(int devFile, int numBytes)
{
    uint16_t readBuf;

    read(devFile, &readBuf, 1);

    return readBuf;
}
```

Do I need to use SMBus commands or read/write is sufficient ?
Are there any test applications, like in the case of SPIdev ?

Comment: you should provide a minimal example which reflects your problem, what have you tried to localize this issue?

Comment: I just tried to get data from the sensor using this user-space i2c-dev code (using kernel documentation as an example), but did not get any data. So I wanted to know whether this is the correct way to implement the i2c-dev interface or not.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know interface to your chip.  There is a great range of possible ways to use I2C.  But there is a very common way to access a device with 8-bit registers, so let's assume that is what you need.

To read a register, you want to generate the (simplified) primitive I2C sequence:

```
Start I2CAddr+Write RegAddr Start I2CAddr+Read [DATA] Stop
```

But what you are doing is this:

```
Start I2CAddr+Write RegAddr Stop
Start I2CAddr+Read [DATA] Stop
```

Basically, you need the read register operation to be a single transaction with one stop at the end and a repeated start between write mode and read mode.  But what you are sending is two transactions.

You should not be using the `read()`/`write()` interface to i2c-dev.  This interface is very simple and not suitable for most I2C transactions.  Instead use the `ioctl()` interface and `I2C_RDWR`.  This allows the appropriate transactions to be generated.

Since certain forms of transactions are very common, including the ones you most likely want, there is a library that has them coded already.  Use `i2c_smbus_read_byte_data()` and `i2c_smbus_write_byte_data()` from the library in [i2c-tools](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/utils/i2c-tools/i2c-tools.git/).

As for test programs, there is `i2cget` and `i2cset`, part of the above mentioned i2c-tools, that will be able to do what you want.